# GCC inline assembly as binary array

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

Is there any way in GCC to represent inline `__asm__` as `char[]` array? I want to have something like:

```
void my_func();

char my_code[] = {
    __asm__("callq %0" :: "r" (my_func))
};
```

Later `my_code` will be used as run-time patch, i.e.

```
void another_function();
mprotect(another_function, getpagesize(), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);
memcpy(another_function + offset, my_code, sizeof(my_code));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define a function, compile it, then get it's source machine code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void my_func(void) {}

extern void my_code(void);
extern void my_code_end(void);

__attribute__((__used__)) static void _my_code(void) {
        asm volatile(
                ".globl my_code\n"
                "my_code:\n"
                "  callq *%0\n"
                "  nop\n"
                "  ret\n"
                ".globl my_code_end\n"
                "my_code_end:\n"
                :: "r" (my_func)
        );
}

int main() {
        size_t my_code_len = (uintptr_t)my_code_end - (uintptr_t)my_code;
        const unsigned char *arr = (const char*)my_code;
        printf("my_code[%zu]=", my_code_len);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < my_code_len; ++i) {
                printf("%02x", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
my_code[4]=ffd090c3
```

We can check it's ok from the assembly output:

```
$ objdump -D ./a.out
...
0000000000000727 <my_code>:
 727:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
 729:   90                      nop
 72a:   c3                      retq   
...
```

Comment: What if `_my_code` contains a prologue added by GCC?

Comment: I declare `my_code` within `_my_code`, so if it does contain any prologue, it will be before `my_code` anyway. Probably should refactor a bit, so it's more readable.

Comment: @ivaigult and Kamil: Since you're using `.globl my_code` and so on inside the inline asm, *put it at global scope* instead of inside *another* function with a confusingly similar name.  It's not safe to actually call that function (because it clobbers the red zone without telling the compiler).

Comment: Oh wait, you do need to copy from `_my_code` to `my_code_end`, to get the instruction that puts `my_func` into the register that the asm chose.  And if it did that with a RIP-relative LEA (PIE or shared library) instead of an absolute `mov eax, imm32` (non-PIE executable), copying the instruction somewhere else within the same program will change the address.